# UIFont extension in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I am attempting to write a UIFont extension for Swift written project. I get the error 'AnyObject is not convertible to String'. How do I tackle this. Here's what I've done

```
 func listAllFontsOnSystem(){

    var familyNames = NSArray(array: UIFont.familyNames())
    var fontNames = []
    var indFamily, indFont : NSInteger
    for (indFamily = 0 ; indFamily<familyNames.count; ++indFamily){
    //Error on next line
        fontNames = NSArray(array: UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyNames .objectAtIndex(indFamily)))
        for indFont = 0; indFont<fontNames.count; ++indFont{
        print(fontNames.objectAtIndex(indFont))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyNames.objectAtIndex(indFamily))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

objectAtIndex, being a Objective-C method that returns `id`, returns a `AnyObject` instance in Swift, not a String. You could "cast" that to String.

```
fontNames = NSArray(array: UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(
               familyNames.objectAtIndex(indFamily) as String))
```

This is how a version with more Swift and less Objective-C would look like:

```
class func listAllFontsOnSystem2(){
    let familyNames = UIFont.familyNames() as [String]
    for familyName in familyNames {
        let fontNames = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName) as [String]
        for fontName in fontNames {
            println(fontName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MattiasBauch thanks for the explanation, much appreciated. I love how minimal code is needed in Swift :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. The `UIFont.familyNames` returns an array of `AnyObject` i.e.  `[AnyObject]`. It has to be cast to an array of String i.e. `[String]`.

```
func listAllFontsOnSystem(){

    var familyNames =  UIFont.familyNames() as [String]
    for familyName in familyNames {
        let fontNames = UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName) as [String]
        for fontName in fontNames {
            println(fontName)
        }
    }
}
```